# I can't specify a custom error log in PHP

Tags: php, ini-set

```
ini_set('error_log', $custom_error_log_location);  
print ini_get('error_log');
```

The result of the above code? Nothing! It literally prints nothing as the value of `ini_get('error_log')`. I'm running this on an Apache server. I investigated the Apache configuration for my website. The Apache configuration has its own error log setup through the ErrorLog directive. Here's the thing: I'm running another website on the same server, with a similar Apache configuration, and on that site I CAN specify a custom error log in PHP.

I also checked the site's php.ini file. Nothing on logging there. What I want to know is, is there some configuration in either Apache or php.ini that would prevent me from modifying where the error log file is located?

Comment: Obvious question, is `$custom_error_log_location` set correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is. By any chance, and this is a long shot, does PHP validate the path and replace it with a blank value if the validation fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `safe_mode` or `open_basedir` are in effect, `ini_set("error_log")` is restricted by those settings (because you can write anything in the opened file with `error_log()`).

The restriction covers both runtime and `.htaccess`, but you can use the `php_value` directive to set it in the virtual host configuration file.

Comment: Yes, it was that blasted safe_mode to blame.

Comment: Got on this question googling for "php.ini error_log value is error_log" in my phpinfo I can see error_log and it's value is error_log. Do you know in what directory I should be looking?

Answer (score 1):

The `error_log` setting belongs to `PHP_INI_ALL` which can be set anywhere. So there should be nothing wrong with your code.

By "prints nothing as the value of `ini_get('error_log')`", it might be your `$custom_error_log_location` is empty or null, I'd suggest a `var_dump()` on the `$custom_error_log_location` and `ini_get('error_log')` for debugging, instead of print.

Comment: Nope, I dumped the value of the variable. I know that I'm not passing in an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had `safe_mode` on, that's all.